# Setting ethernet proxy settings without WiFi

Tags: proxy, android-x86, virtualbox

I'm playing around with the latest android-x86 (4.4) in virtualbox. The setup can connect to the external network only through a NAT ethernet device that is emulated by virtual box. This gets autoconfigured just fine and i can ping computers on my LAN.

If I `export http_proxy=<host>:<port>` in a terminal, I can `wget` web pages. However I am unable to set the proxy settings globally for all apps.

The proxy settings are displayed only after a wifi network is connected, and I lack any wifi devices in the virtual machine.

I have tried the following in the root terminal accesible from `alt+f1`:

```
setprop global_http_proxy_host <host>
setprop global_http_proxy_port <port>
setprop net.gprs.http-proxy http://<host>:<port>
```

But this fails to have any effect. Even new terminals lack the env variable for the proxy. These settings appear to be set when I check it by executing `getprop`

I found [this link](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/2abbacb7d46657e5863eb2ef0035521ffc41a0a8/src/com/android/settings/ProxySelector.java) to the fragment that seems to display the proxys selector for the wifi.

Is there any way that I can manually set all the settings that are affected by this fragment?

Comment: If Android version is 6 or 7, here is the solution: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/186820

Answer (score 6):

This solution worked for me.

Just enter the following command in a terminal (change `PROXYIP:PROXYPORT` )

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to PROXYIP:PROXYPORT
```

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-x86/XfIRyHQ5nmk

I had too tried all your commands without success. I was stuck behind a proxy trying to setup Android x86 with a VirtualBox VM which only had eth0. I was stuck at the activation screen not resolving the needed webpages to continue into the OS. After running the above command, I was able to reach the web and continue. Results may vary per proxy environment.

Edit: This didn't get me too far, but it got me somewhere. The same trick didn't work for 443.

Comment: Were you able to get it working for 443?
I can't get ssl connections proxied no matter what I do. Http works fine.

Comment: Check SandroProxy has options to foward to proxy to proxy

Comment: protoent* getprotobyname(char const*)(3) is not implemented on Android

Comment: @Saurabh3321 transparently proxying `https` requires SSL bump (MITM). You need to add proxy's CA to device/app.